# Change the default color of a Link

Tags: html, css

In My code I have

```
<div class="row-fluid"><div class="span12" style="color:red"><a href="/event/alert/recipient/list/${alertStatusForm.forAlert.id}" class="underline">${fn:length(alertStatusForm.totalNotSentRecipient)}</a></div></div>
```

Still Its not working
Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this
`.span12 a{
color:#000;
}`

Answer (score 3):

You must apply the CSS directly to the `<a>`. `<a>` elements will not inherit the font color by default.

CSS:

```
.span12 a{
   color: red
}
a:visited{
   color: red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.span12 a
{
color : #FF0000;
}
.span12 a:visited
{
color: #FF0000;
}
```